# Can't write to Docker volume

Tags: docker

#### My set-up

- I have a Docker image based on `php:7.4-apache`.
- I have two Docker volumes for saving files that need to be persisted.
- On container start, I run [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) to install HTTPs certificates.

#### Issue

I discovered that **my application can't write to Docker volumes**.

#### Debugging

Using `ls -l` I found out that the mountpoints of my volumes are owned by user `1451`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4     1451 users     176128 Mar 12 13:25 volume_mountpoint
```

My web server is running under user `www-data`.

#### Attempted solution

I've tried setting the user under which my container runs to `www-data`. This caused the volume mountpoints to be owned by `www-data`, which fixed the permissions issue. The problem with this solution is that `Certbot` requires `root` permissions and fails to acquire HTTPs certificate without it.

#### Question

What is the proper way to fix this issue? I need `Certbot` to run under root, but let mountpoints to be owned by `www-data`.

Comment: This is a bit strange because Docker by default uses the *root* user are you saying that initially it was instead using a user with id 1451? Also what OS are you using?

Comment: I’m running Docker on Windows. The image is based on Debian.